# Xcodebuild excruciatingly slow

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcodebuild

I use TeamCity CI to build my Apps, when I build them using xcode (any configuration), a clean build takes just less than 1.5 minutes, but when I run the same command in xcodebuild its excruciatingly slow, take more than 10 minutes. Any ideas why this is happening?

I use precompiled prefix header and even tried to filter the console output to just warnings and errors, still its like 10 minutes.. :(

```
xcodebuild -project %appname%.xcodeproj -configuration AdHoc -sdk iphoneos4.2 clean build -target Aggregation PROVISIONING_PROFILE=%PROVISIONING% | grep -P "(warning|error)"
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I just encountered the same and tracked it down to a single .m file that has a large number of lines (15K+) in it. I would prefer to address this without having to change that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution is to mount a ramdisk and make sure the compilation happens from Ramdisk, I have tried this and does improve performance

http://www.kolios.dk/2011/03/29/using-a-ramdisk-when-compiling-a-project/